# upgrade to rails 3 sometimes extremly slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've just upgraded to rails 3. Beside some problems on the page I experience as well a strange latency after running the test environment for a while... The speed is normal but after a few clicks on the page, it suddenly "freezes" and needs about a minute to load the page. Unfortunately it doesn't matter where I click though. Just after the test environment was running for a while it shows up to suddenly have this problem. Even when I want to stop the server it needs a minute to do so. Restarting the server let it working for a while

Thanks for any help
Markus

Comment: I see the exact same thing. And sometimes if there is an syntax error on a view template, there's a race condition that causes my computer to lock up unless I can kill those ruby processes fast enough.

Comment: What OS are you using?  Have you looked at the memory footprint or CPU usage of the ruby process while it is slow?  Also, just out of curiosity, why are you running the test environment with your app server?  Why not run in the development environment instead and use the test environment for automated tests.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Mac or Linux, try installing [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) and installing [Ruby Enterprise Edition](http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/) .